# How to sync InfluxDB with Elasticsrearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, influxdb, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to synchronize an influxDB database with elasticsearch, because I want to use Kibana instead of Grafana, but I can't find any plugins to do it.

Is there a plugin I can use?

Is there any way to synchronize only the data I need?